# How to create a private Google Group that anyone can request to join?

Tags: google-groups

I'm creating a Google Group and would prefer to not have it visible to anyone. Can I do this and allow people to request to join the group? If so, how do they make the request?

Here are the Group's Basic Permissions:

[image: Basic Permissions]

Answer (score -1):

Create a separate web page promoting the group and provide a link there for visitors to request membership.

Google Groups have no front page of their own.